# Force Spring MVC to Update Form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Is there a way to force Spring to update all fields of a form-backing object stored in the session?

I'm moving a form in one part of the application from a standard request-scoped form (i.e. where one controller method serves the empty form, and then the next form is the submission of the form).  This works fine with the `@ModelAttribute` annotation on the method argument. But now I'm putting a "Preview" step in between filling out the form and final submission, with the ability to go back to the original form to change data, so I'm now storing the form in the session via the `@SessionAttribute`attribute.  Fine, it all works swimmingly.

Here's the problem: If the user returns to the data-input form and removes some element from the page, then that element is no longer in the HTML `<form>` and consequently Spring never calls the corresponding setter on the POJO, which makes sense, except that there is now stale data in the POJO stored in the session from the first submission.

This can easily enough be accounted for by doing something like `<input name="objectIds" type="hidden" value="">`, which will cause Spring's form binder to do the update for the `objectIds` field, but then I have an array with a `null` value instead of just a `null` field, requiring some defensive coding in either the form POJO or the controller.

Neither of those options is difficult, but they seem like hacks. Is there some annotation/method that Spring MVC provides to force the POJO that backs the form to be updated and set to null if there's not a corresponding element in the HTML form, instead of just not calling the setter?

Comment: Spring MVC has a hard time dealing with collections in general.  The problem is that it really has no way to know if you are simply breaking up your form wizard-style or if you actually meant to clear out the values.  The two ways I have dealt with this conundrum is to either a) Keep some value in the objects in your collection such that you can indicate it needs to be removed (a removal flag), or b) write your validation such that it clears any null entries and send nulls for the removed items.